# mysql decimal data type out of range value for column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to assigne value to decimal column but it is giving me error as `"Mysql2::Error: Out of range value for column"`

```
column lattitude(10,7)
```

As you can see my lattitude column can accept max 10 digits and can accept 7 digits after decimal.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (lattitude) VALUES (1234.12345);
```

I want to know why above sql statement giving me an error. As per my research it should not give me an error because it has total 9 digits and 5 digits after decimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your type can accept 7 digits *after* the decimal place *and* it can accept 10 digits, then the type can accept only 3 digits *before* the decimal place.

Your sample data has four digits before the decimal place, so you would need:

```
latitude decimal(11, 7)
```

Of course, four digits for a latitude doesn't make sense, at least the way latitudes are defined on the surface of the earth.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable and easy to understand comment.